# How to pause main thread in jQuery?

Tags: jquery

Is there any way to pause our main thread in jQuery for a minutes/seconds.

Let take a  example.

I need to print 25 elements, then after few second, I need print 25 to 49 elements?
Similar to  sleep mode in Java. Is there any method which stop processing?

http://jsfiddle.net/ZxhKh/1/

```
for(var i=0;i<50;i++ ){
console.log("---------------"+i);
    if(i==25){
        //stop thread for 1 min ?
    }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: There is only one thread in js. If you sleep it - the browser will hang

Comment: I know setTimeout ..But i know want to use settimeout

Comment: Uh what? Are you saying you don't know how `setTimeout` works? You could have a look at the documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.setTimeout.

Comment: well, you could do it with a while loop that checks the current time, however there are limits to how long the browser will let you do that before it stops it as an infinite loop. And it's a terrible thing to do.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking at `setTimeout`, not threads.

```
for(var i=0;i<=25;i++ ){
       console.log("---------------"+i);  
}
setTimeout(function() {
    for(var i=25;i<50;i++ ){
       console.log("---------------"+i);  
    }
}, 1000); // print after waiting one second
```

The equivalent of sleep would not do what you would want it to do. In a console application, there is seemingly no difference because the user is not doing anything while the program is 'sleeping'. However if you were to sleep the browser thread, it would of course hang the application.

Comment: No.I don't want to go

Comment: any other way ..without using settimeout?